# Copying files from the Raspberry Pi to a USB drive

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

My problem is very basic but it is giving me a lot of trouble.

The OS is Raspbian. I need to copy a few files, (Python codes) from my Raspberry Pi to my USB drive. But whenever I try to copy the files I get this:

```
Errors occurred: 
Name_of_Folder: Error creating Directory: Read-only file system
```

What should I do? I am trying to copy the codes just in case anything happens to the Pi and then I will have to reinstall the SD card from scratch.

Comment: I suggest if possible using something like Filezilla, which will allow you to easily copy files from your Pi to your computer using SSH. Looking at the error you need to do something with your USB drive, if its telling you it is read only.

Comment: What file System is on your US Drive? Did you try a "remount -rw" ?

Comment: Thank you sirs. I thought it was a problem with my Pi but apparently it is my USB drive that's affected with a virus because of using the university's computers. Please do put your answer down bellow so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing the following in your command line:

```
remount -rw
```

This should remount the device and make it read/write-able (`-rw`).

Also, as you stated in the comments above, if it does have a virus on it, be sure to format it to prevent the spread of it getting to your Raspberry Pi or other devices.